# Best practice to base dashboard reporting on Azure DW or Azure SQL?

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse, azure-sql-database

I am struggling to decide on where to do my dashboard reporting on Azure DW or Azure SQL?

I have a dashboard where we run performance aggregate report queries against 50GB of data. We expect few concurrent user running on it. I have created an Azure DW which has dimension and fact tables and ETL process pushes aggregated data to Azure Sql database. As a result I have same set of dimension and fact tables and data available in both databases I am feeling a little confused about options below whether to:

1. run my queries directly in DW and drop Azure SQL database
2. use DW for ETL, push aggregated data to Azure SQL database, clean DW up after ETL, run reporting queries on Azure Sql database. (This way my dimension table data have to be exist in both places and maintained).

Please advise based on your experience and best practices.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question, but is this what you are doing?

> DataSource -> Azure SQL Data Warehouse -> Azure SQL

If so, I'd have to question your intent.

If your total volume of data is only 50Gb, then you're probably not going to benefit from Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Just push your data from DataSource to Azure SQL.

If you do have enough data, or really do want to use Azure SQL Data Warehouse, your best option for fast reporting is this:

> DataSource -> Azure SQL Data Warehouse -> Azure Analysis Services

In other words, create a tabular model in AAS, and report from it using PowerBI and/or SSRS.

Comment: thanks for response. Yes it is what i am doing currently: DataSource -> Azure SQL Data Warehouse -> Azure SQL. This system will support a lot of data Tbs but currently have 50Gb. We have our own dashboard application so AAS is not an option.

Comment: Why are you moving data back to Azure SQL? That is the part I don't understand.

Comment: Azure DW has limited concurrent query execution slots depending on the DW unit. However Azure SQL this is not an issue therefore querying aggregated data from there seems feasible that is why.

Comment: OK, I understand. You might be surprised at how much work those 32 slots can get through - queries execute VERY quickly - but if you have a very large number of concurrent users, and a large number of queries per page, ASDW isn't your best data source for interactive reporting. That is why Azure Analysis Services is such a good solution, but I also  understand that your current dashboard can't use it.

Comment: Yes, it all really depends too. It's not bad practice to find the right tool for the job. Plenty of people use multiple instances of SQL Server for example, where one is the data warehouse and the other is the data marts. That way the data marts can support reporting. The same goes for Data Warehouse -> SSAS -> Reporting. But if you're using something like PowerBI for reporting that has caching of data and find loading data once a day is fine, then your Azure DW will be fine as is batch loading reporting once a day. But that all depends on you and your business requirements...

Comment: It would be more usual to have Azure SQL DW as the endpoint for your big queries. What are your reasons for putting it in Azure SQL DW? Could you just put it in Azure SQL? Using Azure SQL DW as storage to cope with TB isn't its main purpose and would end up costly, if that's what you're thinking.